# How many GB or TB is 1 hour of raw uncompressed Ultra HD film?

Tags: video-standards

I was looking on wikipedia but couldn't find any definitive answer.

I think it's because it depends on how many bits is the color pallete and frames per second.

Please, could somebody help me make a rough estimate **how much GB or TB** would be a standard **24fps? or 30fps?** (I am not sure which is the standard frame rate for UHD movies) **Ultra HD movie (3840x2160)** with the length of **1 hour**.

I want to know the uncompressed raw size of the movie file after exporting from Adobe Premiere

I am not sure what is the standard 8 or 12 bit or some other? So, I will be thankful for your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some storage calculators: [AJA DataCalc](http://www.aja.com/en/products/software/), [Video Space Calculator](http://www.digitalrebellion.com/webapps/video_calc.html). Nothing complex, but keep also in mind that actual required storage size will be more than raw disk size due formatting, RAID levels etc.

Comment: Thanks but here is http://www.digitalrebellion.com/webapps/video_calc.html only Redcode36 raw which gives me 126 GB. But that is already compressed. BTw. there is I think 42 which is compressed a little less, but still compressed. Any advicce where can I found a calculator that have uncompressed 4K option. On that site is 1080 maximum except redcode.

Comment: Try DataCalc: 1 hour/4K/uncompressed/10 bit + 2ch audio = 3,62 TB.

Answer (score 4):

A 'base' value is ~33 GB per minute for 8-bit RGB at 24fps. Multiply by 1.25 for 30fps, and/or by 1.5 for 12 bits/pixel, or 1.25 for 10 bits/px.

3840x2160 = 8294400 pixels per plane 
 
   x 3 for RGB = 24883200 px per frame 
     x 24 fps = 597196800 px per sec 
       x 60 sec = 3.5831808 x 10^10 px per hour 
         x 8 bits per pixel, / 8 bits per byte = 3.6 x 10^10 bytes / hour 
So, roughly 33 GB per minute for 8-bit 24 fps

Comment: according to this it is 1,6TB and not 33GB http://web.forret.com/tools/video_fps.asp?width=3840&height=2160&fps=24&interlace=on&space=rgb444&depth=12

Comment: @Derfder: You selected 12-bits per color channel, rather than 8. You also selected interlaced, which halves it. Though he forgot that there are 3600 seconds in an hour, not 60; that's why his calculations are off. He's computed 33GB per minute.

Comment: Heh, this pops up again a year later. And yes, I slipped and computed the per minute size -- multiply by 60 to get the hourly rate.